# Plotly/Dash: How to prevent dynamically inserted link/element from firing callback automatically without user clicking it?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I have a clickable image gallery that creates some preview thumbnail.

[
`html.A(id=_id, children=html.Img(src=src, height=300, id=image_id, style={'margin': '10px'}))`
,... ]

which are dynamically inserted in a Div. The first images 'clicked' callback fires when the list is generated.
Which then forces another element to load some content. The user can now change or delete an image which updates the thumbnails. Though, then the first image sends a click again. The problem is that the image was never clicked and now forces the other elements to load something completely wrong. Is it possible to prevent that from happening?

I tried

```
    @app.callback(
        Output('pko-image-clicked-output', 'children'),
        [Input({'type': 'image', 'index': ALL}, 'n_clicks')],
        prevent_initial_call=True
        )
    def pko_image_clicked(ndx):
        if ndx is None or len(ndx)==0: raise PreventUpdate
        ctx = dash.callback_context
        clicked = ctx.triggered[0]['prop_id']
        clicked = clicked.replace('{"index":"', '')
        clicked = clicked.split('","type":')[0].replace('\\', '')
        print('Clicked:', clicked)
        return clicked
```

which did not work. I have a multi page app which requires:

```
app.config['suppress_callback_exceptions'] = True
```

Which gets activated (fires a callback of the first image) when this component is done:

```
def callbacks(app, fsc, cache):
        
    @app.callback(
    Output('pko-dropdown', 'options'),
    Input('tab', 'value'),
    Input('pko-delete-output', 'children'),
    State('wdir', 'children'),
    State('pko-dropdown', 'options'),
    )
    def pko_controls(tab, peak_deleted, wdir, old_options):
        if tab != 'pko':
            raise PreventUpdate
        peaklist = T.get_peaklist( wdir )
        if peaklist is None:
            raise PreventUpdate
        options = [{'label':label, 'value': i} for i, label in enumerate(peaklist.index)]
        if options == old_options:
            raise PreventUpdate
        return options
```

Comment: What is the content of ndx in the initial (undesired) call?

Comment: ndx is a string,I should rename that to label. It was an integer before... it is the label of an image.

Comment: I am sorry, you are totally right, ndx is a list of integers. I am then creating the string from the callback context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure `ndx` is a string. You're using `ALL` of the `n_click` properties, so I think it should be a list of `int`s. You can try two things.

```py
if not any(ndx):
    raise PreventUpdate
```

and if that doesn't work, you could also do:

```py
if len(dash.callback_context.triggered[0]) > 1:
    raise PreventUpdate
```

I've had to deal with the same problem, so I think one of those at least should work. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: `if len( dash.callback_context.triggered) > 1: raise PreventUpdate` worked!! You can change it to this and I will accept the answer.